# How to use count with limit function in codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

i have some model like this,

```
public function get_payment_method($date_from, $date_to){     
        $op_status = array('settlement','capture');

        $this->db->select('op_payment_code,COUNT(order_id) as total,pc_caption');
        $this->db->from("(dashboard_sales)");
        $this->db->where('order_date BETWEEN "'. date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($date_from)). '" and "'. date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime($date_to)).'"');
        $this->db->where_in('op_status',$op_status);
        $this->db->where('pc_caption is NOT NULL', NULL, FALSE);
        $this->db->group_by('op_payment_code');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

but when I check my database there is duplicate data on order_id as below,

[image]

the question is how to do count only once at order_id? so if there is the same order_id then it will not be counted

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this:

```
$this->db->select('op_payment_code, COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) as total, pc_caption', false);
```